How can I resolve PowerShell script "cannot index null value" from line 6 of the code below
# Set the number of days to look back
$DaysBack = 7

# Get the current date and time
$EndDate = Get-Date

# Calculate the start date
$StartDate = $EndDate.AddDays(-$DaysBack)

# Get the list of users who have logged in
$UserLogins = Get-EventLog -LogName 'Security' -InstanceId 4624 -After $StartDate -Before $EndDate

# Display the list of users
$UserLogins | ForEach-Object {
    $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
} | Sort-Object -Unique

Hello guys . I wrote the PowerShell script to obtain users who logged into my domain the last days and I'm getting an error on line 6
'Cannot index ... null value

The error implies that $_.ReplacementStrings evaluates to $null; PowerShell doesn't let you index into $null.

Please post the exact error message in full

yes you just need to add check on $_.ReplacementStrings aray so that it does not end up having null value at index 5. if the index is populated with null then you are likely to see the error

To filter out the entries without a SID/username you could filter it right at the start of your processing:
# Display the list of users
$UserLogins | Where-Object { $_.ReplacementStrings[5] } | ForEach-Object {
    $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
} | Sort-Object -Unique

If you need to process the entries without a SID/username, you can choose to process them with the inverse:
# Process unknown entries
$UserLogins | Where-Object { -not $_.ReplacementStrings[5] } | ForEach-Object {
    # Do something
}

Alternatively you could use an if-statement in your loop:
# Display the list of users
$UserLogins | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.ReplacementStrings[5]) {
        $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
    }
} | Sort-Object -Unique


Because your filter and conditional also use $_.ReplacementStrings[5], they'll trigger the same error that the question is about.
